# Do I need to balance my data when I am using a logistic regression model for statistical inference and not prediction?

Tags: logistic, mathematical-statistics, inference, biostatistics

I am looking into how various features affect an outcome using a logistic regression model. I do not care about prediction right now. My dataset is imbalanced where class 0 accounts for 88% of the data and class 1 accounts for 12% of the data. Do I need to balance my dataset beforehand if my goal is inference and not prediction? Is there another way to account for this imbalance, such as utilizing a quasibinomial generalized linear model?

Comment: Implicit in your post is that you believe it is important to balance classes when the goal is prediction. It isn’t.

Comment: Yeah, I was reading this post [here](https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/) by Harrell. I just don't understand then why I am learning in ML that it is important to balance the classes.